# Persistent Uneditable Browser (Client-Side) Storage Object

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am trying to figure out how to store some user information which will control content visibility in a way that will:

- Not require constant trips to the server to query SQL to see what the user does/does not have access to AND
- The user cannot edit in the browser's developer tools/console

Cookies, Query Strings and even HTML5 Local Storage or SQLite are all great storage options, but they can all be edited by a tech savvy user.  How do I control content based on a user's security level while limiting queries and preventing users the ability to hack around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *only* way to prevent the user from seeing specific content is to validate their access to the content *server-side* and not render it to them.  *Any* client-side validation can be circumvented.  Even if you devise a way to locally store information that the user can't see, you'd still be *sending* the content to them and using *client-side* code to check that value.

The user can see any content you send them.

You don't necessarily need to make constant trips to the SQL database to check roles and permissions.  You can persist some cached roles and authorizations server-side, such as in the session state, and validate against those for the life of the user's session.  At that point you're not incurring a performance cost because the user is requesting pages anyway.  With each page request, you would simply determine what the user can or can't see in the response.

Comment: Thanks.  I was afraid that might be the case.  Perhaps I need to post my follow-up as a separate question, but is there a way to store a user-specific static object server side so that I at least don't have to open a SQL connection but rather just query this persistent server side object?

Comment: @jmease: Of course, there are a few ways.  The most common is to store data in the `Session` object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session.aspx  It can be used like a Dictionary... `Session["someKey"] = someValue;`

Comment: Thanks again. I considered session but have a few concerns.  A session can end for any number of reasons which would cause me to force the user to log in again.  Ideally, the user will log in once and if they continue to visit the site regularly they will stay logged in. I guess my best bet is to just create a Dictionary or Generic List in my class that is assigned value on Page_Load (if not a postback) so at the most I am querying this information once per page.  This will be fine for my desktop users, just concerned for mobile users.

Comment: @jmease: The session can end, sure, but you can persist the user's basic authentication token with a cookie.  From the server's perspective the user is "logging in again" by simply having the cookie.  You don't want to put any sensitive information in the cookie, and ASP.NET has built-in mechanisms for persisting the login in this manner.  All the server-side code would have to do is refresh the user context (authorization, etc.) from the database once per session, which is still a lot better than once per page.

Comment: Ah. I see.  So on Page_Load I check for the login cookie, and if it exists but the session variable does not, simply use the information in the cookie to refresh/recreate the session information for use from that point on.  The user would only have to log in if both the session and cookie information was gone.  Nice!  Thanks!